# Добавить python скрипт и аргументы в cron через bash скрипт

Tags: python, bash, cron

Есть скрипт, который я запускаю каждый день для парсинга информации с сайта. Запускаю через консоль, логин и пароль для авторизации на сайте передаю через sys.argv ( аргументы командной строки).

Теперь нужно написать bash скрипт, который добавит этот python-скрипт в cron на ежедневый запуск.

Этот bash скрипт запустим всего один раз, дальше просто cron будет запускать мой python скрипт. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как передать в этот bash скрипт аргументы командной строки для python скрипта, с которыми скрипт будет запускаться ежедневно.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Если бы без аргументов было, то как вы решение себе представляете? Кстати чтобы пароль не светить  можно в файл ~user/.netrc его прописать (для пользователя, который это cron задание выполняет). Чтобы питон скрипт каждый день запускать можно попробовать (не тестировал) добавить в /etc/cron.d папку файл с содержимым: `@daily user /path/to/python-script` не ясно как здесь bash скрипт участвует

Comment: @jfs  1) Без аргументов - просто прямо в скрипте прописать логин пароль, но мне этот вариант не подходит 2) По поводу bash скрипта - мне нужно, что бы человек на другом компьютере добавил этот python скрипт в крон ( со своим логином паролем), и мне проще ( и для личного развития интересней и полезней) написать скрипт, который он запустит ( и передаст как аргумент логин пароль) и тот скрипт добавит в cron python скрипт, чем обьяснить ему что такое cron и т.д.

Comment: если вы знаете как задачу без параметров выполнить, то в чём сложности? Попробуйте разбить вашу задачу на подзадачи и явно укажите какую подзадачу вы не можете самостоятельно выполнить. Я так понял вы хотите реализовать `install.sh`, который вашими пользователями может быть использован как: `curl https://example.com/install.sh | sh` (где install.sh спрашивает пользователя о credentials и записывает их в ~/.netrc, загружает python-script в `~/bin` и прописывает добавляет @daily ~/bin/python-script в пользовательский crontab).

Comment: @Grzegorzg А пробовали просто сделать питоновский скрипт исполняемым и добавить в крон с аргументами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, немного глупый вопрос был.

В bash скрипте просто прописал:

```
sudo crontab -l | { cat; echo "00 14 * * * python [Путь к скрипту] $1 $2  >> /home/$user/log.txt 2>&1"; } | sudo crontab -;
```

И при запуске bash скрипта через косноль первым и вторым аргументом передал логин/пароль. Всем спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

> мне нужно, что бы человек на другом компьютере добавил этот python скрипт в крон ( со своим логином паролем), и мне проще ( и для личного развития интересней и полезней) написать скрипт, который он запустит ( и передаст как аргумент логин пароль) и тот скрипт добавит в cron python скрипт, чем обьяснить ему что такое cron

т.е., вам требуется неинтерактивно добавить нужную строку в файл `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/имя-пользователя`

для этого надо получить текущее содержимое файла:

```
$ crontab -l
```

после этого вывести нужную вам строку:

```
$ echo '15 0 * * * какая-нибудь-программа с параметрами'
```

и записать вывод двух предыдущих команд назад в `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/имя-пользователя`:

```
$ { crontab -l; echo '15 0 * * * какая-нибудь-программа с параметрами'; } | crontab -
```

---

подробнее про аргументы программы *crontab* см. `$ man 1 crontab`